# Using Param in ActionFunction - Unexpected Token ':'

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, apex-param, browser

Using a simple action function and param to pass a value to a controller, but receiving the following in the browser.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Exception caught on ':' in `doAThing=function(j_id0:`

When I remove the param, I do not run into the exception.

**VFP Code:**

```
    <apex:actionFunction name="doAThing" reRender="refreshPanel"
                         onComplete="doThisOnComplete()" action="{!doAThing}">
    <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!variableFromVfp}"></apex:param>    
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

**Rendered in the browser as:**

```
<script id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id7" type="text/javascript">
doAThing=function(j_id0:j_id1:j_id8){A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1',null,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id7','oncomplete':function(request,event,data){proceed()},'parameters':{'j_id0:j_id1:j_id7':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id7','j_id0:j_id1:j_id8':(typeof j_id0:j_id1:j_id8!='undefined'&&j_id0:j_id1:j_id8!=null)?j_id0:j_id1:j_id8:''} } )};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a name attribute, or you would get unexpected behavior.

```
<apex:param name="aValue" value="" assignTo="{!variableFromVfp}"></apex:param>
```

Comment: Thanks, but whats the cause for the unexpected behavior? Name attribute is not a required field according to the docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm When this converts to a JS function on the page, why does it need a name?

Comment: @S.B. Thanks for reminding me, it's been a while. Actually, name isn't needed if you do not use `reRender` on the parent element, everything just works. However, because of how VF generates names, the AJAX framework used for reRender, and the rules of JavaScript, not providing a name causes this behavior. I'm going to bring this up with the doc team (for the second time, if I recall), because the docs are misleading and/or the platform is not working as documented. For now, just pretend name is actually documented as being required.